# HTTP request with api key fails for AWS v4 API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, http, api-key

I am able to get successful response from AWS V4 API with api key using CURL with syntax:

`curl --location 'https://api.develop.com' \ --header 'x-api-key: api-key'`

But when I implement the HTTP request for the same I get 401. Replace actual URL with **https://api.develop.com** and actual api-key with **api-key**

```rb
require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://api.develop.com")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["x-api-key"] = api_key

response = https.request(request)
```

Any suggestions about why a curl request is successful and the same request using Ruby HTTP libraries return 401.

I haven't faced an issue like this before. I have tried the same request using Net::HTTp, HTTParty and RestClient in ruby.